# Normalizer of solvable linear group is an algebraic group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

I am trying to read the article "[Three-dimensional affine crystallographic groups](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(83)90053-1)" of Fried–Goldman (Adv. Math., 1983). At some place, it states that if $G$ is a connected solvable closed subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb R^n)$, then its normalizer in $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb R^n)$ is an algebraic group. I couldn't see how this works. I would like to know if this is a classical fact, and if there is any reference on that ?

Comment: The normalizer of every connected closed subgroup is the stabilizer of its Lie algebra, so is Zariski-closed.

Comment: This seems a reasonable question for someone who is coming to this paper from the point of view of analysis / diff geom but who is not so familiar with Lie theory

Comment: @YCor Yes I see now, thank you !

Comment: Your title mentions that $G$ is linear, but your body does not.  Is that intentional?  (The normaliser of *any* (Zariski-closed) linear subgroup of a linear group is linear.)

Comment: @LSpice the body says that $G$ is in $\mathrm{GL}_n$ and the normalizer is the normalizer in $\mathrm{GL}_n$.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459594/normalizer-of-solvable-linear-group-is-an-algebraic-group#comment1190940_459594), I thought that a linear subgroup was required to be a *Zariski* closed, not just an *analytically* closed, subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$.  (I took "closed" to mean "closed in the analytic (i.e., Euclidean) topology", anyway.)

Comment: @LSpice but "linear group" is quite vague/informal without context. Here the title is a bit vague and the question in the body is clear, so it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

The normalizer of every connected closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is the stabilizer of its Lie algebra, so is Zariski-closed.